# How can I get the SHA number of previous commit?

Tags: git

For my research I need few data, one of which is the SHA number for the previous commit i.e if I give a particular commit number/SHA number, I should be able to get the SHA number before it.

Help me with the git command to get the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git rev-list --parents -n 1 SOME_COMMIT` will give you the SHA of the commit you specified follow by the SHA of its parent(s).

Comment: +1: This is a nice way to get all the parents without having to know in advance how many parents a merge commit has.  I prefer to use `--no-walk` instead of `-n 1` but the effect is exactly the same.

Answer (score 7):

The command to *translate* any specifier into a hash ID is `git rev-parse`.

The *syntax that means* "find the parent commit of a commit" is from [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), and is `commit^` or `commit~`—use whichever you prefer to type.  The *`commit`* part can be nearly any valid commit specifier, including a branch name, another commit hash ID, the special name `HEAD`, or another one of these suffixed expressions.

Hence:

```
HEAD^
```

is the parent of `HEAD`, and:

```
HEAD^^
```

is the parent of `HEAD^`, and so on.

The tilde syntax is actually a compressed version of many hat suffixes, so:

```
HEAD~5
```

means the same thing as:

```
HEAD^^^^^
```

If the number after the tilde is missing, Git assumes you meant `1`.

What all this means, put together, is that:

```
git rev-parse HEAD^
```

(or `HEAD~`) will get you the actual hash ID.  But you can just write `HEAD^` or `HEAD~` instead, with any normal Git command.  Similarly, if `1234567` is a valid shortened commit hash ID, you can write `1234567^` or `1234567~1` to refer to its parent commit.

(Commits that are *merge* commits have two or more parents, in which case there is more syntax available to extract each parent one at a time, or to refer to all parents.  Again, see [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for details.)

Answer (score 2):

`git log --format="%H" -n 1 <commit>~` outputs just the hash (%H) and limits the output to 1 entry (instead of displaying all ancestors) from the commit's parent (~).